# Java GCP bigquery simba jdbc connection timeout

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, simba

I am trying to connect GCP bigQuery from local using simba jdbc but getting error. Previously I had got Service account role permission issue , those were resolved by adding necessary roles for service account

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100004) HttpTransport IO error : Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out, iss: xx@xx.gserviceaccount.com.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.createAndTestClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.authenticateAndTest(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getSimbaConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100004) HttpTransport IO error : Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out, iss: xx@xx.gserviceaccount.com.
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.exceptions.JobExecutionErrorException: EXEC_JOB_EXECUTION_ERR
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.jobs.JobsInsertRequest.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.AbstractRequestWithRetry.executeWithRetry(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.queryclient.QueryClient.executeDryRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.createAndTestClient(Unk

import com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.DataSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TEstConnection {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Connection check");

  Connection connection = null;
  DataSource ds = new
          com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.DataSource();
  ds.setProjectId("xxx");
  ds.setOAuthPvtKeyFilePath("C:\\Users\\xx\\UI\\GCP\\devgcp.json");
  ds.setOAuthType(0);
  ds.setOAuthServiceAcctEmail("xx@xx.gserviceaccount.com");
  ds.setURL("jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443");
  ds.setTimeout(40000000L);
  try {
   connection = ds.getConnection();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

The service account has required role permission but still I am getting error

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways authenticating your service account. You might have done either of the two: `OAuth 2.0` and `Service Account based` authentication
And you might want to do the authentication again.

Here is a URL to use to connect to Google BigQuery using [Progress DataDirect BigQuery JDBC Connector](https://www.progress.com/connectors/google-bigquery) using Service Account based authentication.

```
jdbc:datadirect:googlebigquery:AuthenticationMethod=serviceaccount;Project=your-project-id;Dataset=your-dataset;ServiceAccountEmail=abc@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com;ServiceAccountPrivateKey=/path/to/json-key-file
```

To authenticate the service account via **OAuth 2.0**, access and refresh tokens are needed. To get the tokens, **OAuth ClientID** must be created to get **ClientID** and **Client Secret** needed to get the **authorization code**. Here is the complete and detailed [guide](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/a-complete-guide-for-google-bigquery-authentication) on how to authenticate via OAuth 2.0.